# Does this constructor return a instance?

Tags: c++, constructor

```
virtual BOOL Create( 
    LPCTSTR lpszCaption, 
    DWORD dwStyle, 
    const RECT& rect,  //we need to pass a RECT instance
    CWnd* pParentWnd, 
    UINT nID  
);

// Create a push button.
myButton1.Create(_T("My button"), WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|BS_PUSHBUTTON, 
CRect(10,10,100,30), pParentWnd, 1);
```

`CRect(10,10,100,30)` is a constructor,does this mean the constructor return a instance?

Answer (score 1):

//CRect(10,10,100,30) is a constructor...

No it is not. It is the declaration of an object. It does call the constructor but the object is created locally, not returned by the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This code is equivalent to the following :

```
CRect rect = CRect(10,10,100,30);

// Create a push button.
myButton1.Create(_T("My button"), WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|BS_PUSHBUTTON, 
rect, pParentWnd, 1);
```

The constructor returns an instance of the class it is constructed, which is used by the Create function.

Comment: So the "new" is optional?

Comment: No, there's fundamental difference between `X()` and `new X()`

Comment: `CRect rect = CRect(10,10,100,30);` allocates an object with automatic storage duration. This means that it is deallocated when it leaves scope. `new` would allocate the object with dynamic storage duration, meaning it would have to be explicitly deallocated.

Comment: @CharlesKong, `new` cannot be used here. `new CRect(10,10,100,30)` returns a `CRect *`, whereas `CRect(10,10,100,30)` simply returns a `CRect`.  The function requires a `CRect`, not a `CRect *`.